# How to stop page loading image when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowProgress() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var modal = $('<div />');
            modal.addClass("modal");
            $('body').append(modal);
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
        }, 2);
</script>
```

**C#**

On button rowcommand

```
string script = "$(document).ready(function () { $('[id*=GridView1_EmailSendbtn_1]').click(ShowProgress()); });";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "load", script, true);
```

this is the ajax that fires when the button is clicked but it keeps on loading even when I refresh the page. 
I need it to stop when the page is refreshed.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: first of all, i didn't see any ajax thing in the question. When are you registering your ClientScript? On button click? can you post button's event handler?

Comment: Your GridView are inside an UpdatePanel? If so, the page is not being refreshed

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the parenthesis from ShowProgress function? like below.

```
string script = "$(document).ready(function () { ('[id*=GridView1_EmailSendbtn_1]').click(ShowProgress); });";
```

Comment: This function is working fine. I need another one to stop when I refresh the page

Comment: I believe the ShowProgress will always be called when you refresh the page because you are triggering ShowProgress() on doc.ready  and not assigning the function 'name' (only) to the click handler. Besides i doubt if the showProgress will ever be triggered on click event. If you want the function the stop on page refresh/reload, I suggest that you use `ShowProgress` and not `ShowProgress()` inside the click handler.